# How to create a table in python3 which can put an entire list into a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following datastructure, which I want to display in a python table in a terminal. Instead of creating a custom parser, I wanted to use a library like pandas to do so

Example data:

```
 roles/storage.objectCreator, Members: ['serviceAccount:127124336329@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com', 'serviceAccount:1011952085846@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com', 'serviceAccount:deployer@serapis-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com']
```

Desired output

```
**ROLE**                               **MEMBERS**
roles/storage.objectCreator        serviceAccount:127124336329@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
                                   serviceAccount:1011952085846@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
                                   serviceAccount:deployer@myproj-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com
roles/storage.objectViewer         serviceAccount:k8s-node@myproj-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com
                                   serviceAccount:k8s-node@dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

In the original data structure, members is a list, for each role in IAM binding